# Collision response for rectangles

Tags: physics, collision

I've been working on a physics engine for about a week now, being stuck for several days trying to work out how to resolve collisions.

My problem is that if there's a box stuck in the middle of 2 other boxes, or between a box and a wall, my application will get stuck in a while loop. It wont resolve the collisions.

This is my code (note: if collision is right side, it means that object A is colliding against object B with its right side. Distance is negative because the objects are inside eachother, and it's in x or y axis depending on side of collision. If you need more code, for example the collision class, which is simply a container of the 2 objects, i can provide that.):

edit: Code edited with new way of dealing with collisions:

```
//Move colliding objects so they don't collide anymore.
while (getCollidingAmount(objectVector)){
    for (int i = 0; i < objectVector.size(); i++){
        PhysicsObject* A = objectVector[i];
        if (objectVector[i]->getPhysicsType() != PhysicsType::staticT && A->_collision.size() > 0){
            Collision collision = A->_collision[A->getDeepestPenetrationCollisionIndex(A->_collision)];
            PhysicsObject* B = collision.getObject();


            switch (collision.getSide()){
            case SideOfCollision::left:
            case SideOfCollision::top:
                //Opposite velocity
                if (A->_saveVelocity.x < 0 && B->_saveVelocity.x > 0){
                    long double percentageOfVelocity = std::min(abs(B->_saveVelocity.x), abs(A->_saveVelocity.x)) /
                        std::max(abs(B->_saveVelocity.x), abs(A->_saveVelocity.x));
                    A->_position.x -= percentageOfVelocity*collision.getVectorPenetration().x;
                    A->_position.y -= percentageOfVelocity*collision.getVectorPenetration().y;
                }
                else{
                    A->_position.x -= collision.getVectorPenetration().x;
                    A->_position.y -= collision.getVectorPenetration().y;
                }                       
                break;

            case SideOfCollision::right:
            case SideOfCollision::bottom:
                //Opposite velocity
                if (A->_saveVelocity.x > 0 && B->_saveVelocity.x < 0){
                    long double percentageOfVelocity = 1 - std::min(abs(B->_saveVelocity.x), abs(A->_saveVelocity.x)) /
                        std::max(abs(B->_saveVelocity.x), abs(A->_saveVelocity.x));
                    A->_position.x -= percentageOfVelocity*collision.getVectorPenetration().x;
                    A->_position.y -= percentageOfVelocity*collision.getVectorPenetration().y;
                }
                else{
                    A->_position.x -= collision.getVectorPenetration().x;
                    A->_position.y -= collision.getVectorPenetration().y;
                }
                break;
            }
            updateCollisions(objectVector);
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

Something wrong with my trigonometry in bottom and top collisions:

```
sf::Vector2<long double> Collision::getVectorPenetration() const{
long double x;
long double y;
long double velX = _object->getVelocity().x;
long double velY = _object->getVelocity().y;
long double angle = atan2(velY, velX);

if (_side == SideOfCollision::left || _side == SideOfCollision::right){
    x = getDistance();
    y = x * tan(angle);
    return sf::Vector2<long double>(x, y);
}
else if (_side == SideOfCollision::top || _side == SideOfCollision::bottom){
    y = getDistance();
    x = y / tan(angle);
    return sf::Vector2<long double>(x, y);
}
```

}

### Update 2

Thanks to Aiman, i solved my issue. Updated my collisionResponse code aswell to match my new way of dealing with collisions. I'm having another issue now where gravity makes it so i can't move in X direction when touching another object. If anyone familiar with this issue wants to give any tips to solve it, i appreciate it :).

### Update 3

So it seems gravity is not actually the problem since i can swap gravity to the x axis, and then be able to slide boxes along the walls. There seems to still be something wrong with the trigonometry.

Comment: That's exactly why physics libraries let you set a maximum number of iterations for position and velocity solvers. If the number is exceeded, you simply break out of the loop.

Comment: But then things will still be colliding, that's why it's not breaking the loop. there are still collisions. However i might try this approach that i found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578656/collision-between-multiple-objects?rq=1 Not sure if it will help in my case or not.

Comment: I've somewhat done what the link i posted suggested, and i've got it working!, for the x-axis.. When i collide on the y-axis (top or bottom), the boxes pull to the left.

The only place where i do something different in x or y axis is in this code right here. Can you tell me if my trigonometry is wrong when trying to find the penetration depth in top and bottom collision?

Going to add code for the trigonometry stuff in main post.

Comment: I really like your code style. `y = x / cos(angle);` and `x = y / sin(angle);` should be `y = x * tan(angle)` and `x = y/tan(angle)` respectively. But yes, you really should put an iteration limit for both, position and velocity solvers, because right now your algorithm execution time tends to infinity. You certainly don't want your physics engine to freeze the whole application at a frame because it had to go through 10000 iterations to solve a tricky 1 pixel contact.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't know why i didn't realize that i should use tan. I sketched it on a piece of paper and can see that now :). Thanks alot, your code changes made it work!

Unfortunately this new approach of moving in both x and y made it so i can't move along the ground because of gravity constantly putting me back to the original spot in x axis.

Thanks for your comment about my code aswell, although i think my collision response code is pretty messy. It's alot cleaner now though, i'll post the updated code in my main post.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of many ways to approach the problem.

**1-**The more complicated one is to **introduce friction**. Here is how I'd implement it, though this is untested and there is a chance I missed something in my train of thought.

Every shape gets a friction constant, and according to those your objects slide when they collide.

First, you need to get the angle that is perpendicular to your surface. To do this, you just get the `arctan` of the the surface's normal slope. The normal is simply `-1/m`, where `m` is the slope of your surface (which you is the ratio/quotient of how much the surface extends in `y` to/by how much it extends in `x`). Let's call this angle `sNormal` for "surface normal". We may also need `sAngle`-"surface angle" for later (you find that by `arctan(m)`). There remains some ambiguity in the angle that has to do with whether you're talking about the 'front' or the 'back' of the surface. You'll have to deal with that manually.

Next, you need the angle of the trajectory your object flies in, which you already know how to find (`atan2(y,x)`). We'll call this angle `oAngle` for "object's surface angle". Next, you calculate `deltaAngle = sNormal - oAngle`. This angle represents how much momentum was *not* blocked completely by the surface. A `deltaAngle` of 0 means all momentum is gone, and a value of `PI/2` or `90` means the 2 surfaces are in parallel touching each other not blocking any momentum at all. Anything in between, we interpolate:

```
newSpeed = objectSpeed * deltaAngle/(PI/2);
newVelocity.x = cos(sAngle) * objectSpeed;
newVelocity.y = sin(sAngle) * objectSpeed;
```

Now this assumes 0 friction. If we let a friction of `1` be the maximum friction which doesn't allow the object to "slide", we modify the newSpeed before we apply the `newVelocity` values, like so: `newSpeed *= (1-friction);`.

And there we have it! Just give your platform a friction value of less than 1 and your box will be able to slide. If you're dealing with upright boxes, then the surface angle is `PI` for top wall, `0` for the bottom, `PI/2` for the right and `-PI/2` for the left wall.

**2-The simpler option is to subtract gravity from the object's y-velocity in the solver's calculation.**

Comment: Thanks for your post. Unfortunately i think that gravity is not the issue. My gravity can be set to the X or Y axis. I've tested now to set it to the X axis, and when it's is on the X axis i can move along the wall properly. So i think that the gravity is not the issue, there is still something else wrong.

I've tried pretty much everything with the trigonometry formulas. If you wants to take a look at the full code, i've uploaded a visual studio 2013 project.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zpl9t6arziebitv/AABUDdHYhiLN0gj8U0XehtHla?dl=0

Comment: There are some things i'd like to change with how i set acceleration, velocity, force etc, but it works. Where you should be looking is in physicsSystem class collisionResponse() function (first part, not the one dealing with velocity handling), and in the Collision class.

Comment: Also, some things you might want to know in order to test the system (if you do that). you can jump with space and move with a and d, and you can set the starting velocity and position of the objects in the main function. in top PhysicsSystem class cpp file you can change the gravity, to see the differance between x and y axis.

Comment: I forgot to say that you need the SFML library to build it. Maybe it's a bit much too ask, but i'm kinda stuck. Here is sfml if you want to download it: http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.3.2/